# Added ScrollView and now my App is pushed to the top

Tags: android, xml, uiscrollview

So my app gets scrolled to the top and I can't see the toppings to pick from for my coffee. This only happened when I added the ScrollView. I added a weight and tried to mess with it but couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Toppings"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Whipped cream"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chocolate_topping_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Chocolate"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:onClick="minusIncrement"
            android:text="-"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:onClick="plusIncrement"
            android:text="+"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="Order Summary"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="$10"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"
        android:text="Order"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView><code>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it myself.... After I posted I saw my mistake.

`<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">`

The ScrollView needed the layout_behavior attribute. Differences shown above